# Installing 12.04 without removing 11.04

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 11.04, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my computer alongside Windows 7.  Is it possible to also dual-boot 12.04?  If not, will I need to overwrite the previous version of Ubuntu?. If so how can I do it?

Comment: To clarify this further, do you want a another Ubuntu alongside Windows or to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04??

Comment: @AvinashRaj: He wants to a triple booted machine with 11.04, 12.04 and windows. If this is not possible, he wants to know whether he needs to overwrite 11.04 with 12.04 and how does he do it.